# Issue with AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My AJAX call to a JSP works when called with drop down menu, but when called with the submit button the content disappears and the page refreshes.

```
function najax() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"testjsp.jsp",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            crid: crid,
            sid: sid,
            ttid: ttid
        },
        async: false,
        cache: true,
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert("error" + error);
            alert("xhr" + xhr);
            alert("status" + status);
        },
        sync: true,
        success: function(responseText) {
            $("#disp_span").html(responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Call to the code:

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit " id="submit"  value="Submit" class="btn"  onClick="najax();" ></input>
```

If I add a drop down menu then it works .

```
<select name="select_menu1" onChange="najax();">
    <option value=" ">Select</option>
    <option value="cr_id">SUBMIT</option>
    <option value="sr_id">CANCEL</option>
```

Comment: change the input type to `button`

Comment: That's because you're having a form here. Any button inside the form will submit the form. Remove the form and see it working.. Nothing wrong with your code

Comment: `Any button inside the form will submit the form` not true. As @Pekka says, if you set the `type` to `button` then it won't submit the parent form.

Comment: What I meant was a submit behaviour. It can also be just an ENTER key inside the form at times

Comment: you want me to call this najax function on the click of the submit button , is it?

`$("#formid").submit(function () { return false; `

Comment: change the input type to button and call the function on button click example `<input type="button" name="Submit " id="submit"  value="Submit" class="btn"></input>` `$('#submit').click(function(){najax()})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid submitting of the form change the input type to `button`

`<input type="button" name="Submit " id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">`

Then on button click call the function

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    //najax()
        //Or call the ajax directly

    $.ajax({
        url: "testjsp.jsp",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            crid: crid,
            sid: sid,
            ttid: ttid
        },
        async: false,
        cache: true,
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert("error" + error);
            alert("xhr" + xhr);
            alert("status" + status);
        },
        sync: true,
        success: function(responseText) {
            $("#disp_span").html(responseText);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: But why is that it will work with the button type and not submit type?

Comment: because if you type is submit it will submit your form that is why it is reloading

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make the ajax call with `submit` button ,then add the submit event to the form.

if you want to prevent the `button` from submitting the form  and perform ajax operation ,then prevent the default action

```
   $('#submit').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
        ....//ajax call 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop the from submit as follows

```
$("#formid").submit(function () { return false; });
```

Comment: But is that what the OP wants?

Comment: This is going to stop the form's submit. If the user does not want to submit the form why use the form in first place?

Comment: Yes that also right. Because if user do not click button and hit enter on any text-field then also the from will be submitted.

Comment: No I am not submitting the form data ,I have tried this thing , by receiving the form data via jquery itself and attaching the function to submit click.

Answer (score 0):

or better yet, just use a `type="button"` button

Answer (score 0):

You put the ajax request in a function, but you dont call it on the submit button like you do on the drop down menu `onChange="najax();"`

```
<input onClick="najax();" type="submit" name="Submit " id="submit"  value="Submit" class="btn"></input>
```

this should work or use jquery to do that for you. :)